# In Arduino, using MCP4725 and Artemis MicroMod Processor, receiving fatal error: cstddef: No such file or directory. How to resolve?

Tags: arduino, sparkfun

I apologize if my formatting of this question is poor as this is my first time submitting a question here but I will do my best to include all possible information.
I am using Arduino IDE version 2.3.2, SparkFun Apollo3 Boards version 2.2.1, and MCP4725 version 0.4.0.

Below is the output messages from compiling my code.

> In file included from C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/mbed-os/mbed.h:39,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/arduino/mbed-bridge/Arduino.h:14,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.h:9,
> from c:\Users\sbrink\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MCP4725/MCP4725.h:10,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\Documents\Arduino\philipsproject\ppg_signal_generator.h:6,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\Documents\Arduino\philipsproject\ppg_signal_generator.c:1:
> C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/mbed-os/platform/platform.h:21:10: fatal error: cstddef: No such file or directory
> #include 
> ^~~~~~~~~
> compilation terminated.
>
> Using library Wire at version 2.0.0 in folder: C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1\libraries\Wire
> Using library MCP4725 at version 0.4.0 in folder: C:\Users\sbrink\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MCP4725
> exit status 1
>
> Compilation error: exit status 1

I am uncertain if I need to include the code files I am trying to compile as it appears to me that these are library compatibility issues; however, if it is necessary to debug the problem, let me know and I will include them.

Previously library compatibility issues existed between the MCP4725.h/MCP4725.cpp and ArduinoSDK.h files. This was due to multiple definitions of PDM between the files. So I commented out the experimental function writePowerDownMode in the MCP4725 files as it was responsible for the multiple definitions and I am not going to be using the function.

Then after recompiling I receieved the above error messages stating "fatal error: cstddef: No such file or directory."

I searched in the apollo3 cores and found <mstd_cstddef> so I tried including that instead of  in the platform.h file. Then the complier told me that , , and  caused fatal directories and could not be found, so I switched to "stdlib.h", "stdio.h", "string.h" and then received these errors:

> n file included from C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/mbed-os/mbed.h:53,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/arduino/mbed-bridge/Arduino.h:14,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.h:9,
> from c:\Users\sbrink\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MCP4725/MCP4725.h:10,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\Documents\Arduino\philipsproject\ppg_signal_generator.h:6,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\Documents\Arduino\philipsproject\ppg_signal_generator.c:1:
> C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/mbed-os/drivers/DigitalIn.h:24:1: error: unknown type name 'namespace'
> namespace mbed {
> ^~~~~~~~~
> C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/mbed-os/drivers/DigitalIn.h:24:16: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before '{' token
> namespace mbed {
> ^
> In file included from C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/mbed-os/mbed.h:54,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/arduino/mbed-bridge/Arduino.h:14,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.h:9,
> from c:\Users\sbrink\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MCP4725/MCP4725.h:10,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\Documents\Arduino\philipsproject\ppg_signal_generator.h:6,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\Documents\Arduino\philipsproject\ppg_signal_generator.c:1:
> C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/mbed-os/drivers/DigitalOut.h:23:1: error: unknown type name 'namespace'
> namespace mbed {
> ^~~~~~~~~
> C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/mbed-os/drivers/DigitalOut.h:23:16: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before '{' token
> namespace mbed {
> ^
> In file included from C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/mbed-os/mbed.h:55,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/arduino/mbed-bridge/Arduino.h:14,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.h:9,
> from c:\Users\sbrink\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MCP4725/MCP4725.h:10,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\Documents\Arduino\philipsproject\ppg_signal_generator.h:6,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\Documents\Arduino\philipsproject\ppg_signal_generator.c:1:
> C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/mbed-os/drivers/DigitalInOut.h:24:1: error: unknown type name 'namespace'
> namespace mbed {
> ^~~~~~~~~
> C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/mbed-os/drivers/DigitalInOut.h:24:16: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before '{' token
> namespace mbed {
> ^
> In file included from C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/mbed-os/platform/PlatformMutex.h:20,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/mbed-os/drivers/BusIn.h:22,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/mbed-os/mbed.h:56,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/arduino/mbed-bridge/Arduino.h:14,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.h:9,
> from c:\Users\sbrink\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MCP4725/MCP4725.h:10,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\Documents\Arduino\philipsproject\ppg_signal_generator.h:6,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\Documents\Arduino\philipsproject\ppg_signal_generator.c:1:
> C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/mbed-os/platform/NonCopyable.h:20:1: error: unknown type name 'namespace'
> namespace mbed {
> ^~~~~~~~~
> C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/mbed-os/platform/NonCopyable.h:20:16: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before '{' token
> namespace mbed {
> ^
> In file included from C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/mbed-os/drivers/BusIn.h:22,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/mbed-os/mbed.h:56,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/arduino/mbed-bridge/Arduino.h:14,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.h:9,
> from c:\Users\sbrink\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MCP4725/MCP4725.h:10,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\Documents\Arduino\philipsproject\ppg_signal_generator.h:6,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\Documents\Arduino\philipsproject\ppg_signal_generator.c:1:
> C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/mbed-os/platform/PlatformMutex.h:47:1: error: unknown type name 'class'
> class PlatformMutex: private mbed::NonCopyable {
> ^~~~~
> C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/mbed-os/platform/PlatformMutex.h:47:20: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before ':' token
> class PlatformMutex: private mbed::NonCopyable {
> ^
> In file included from C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/mbed-os/mbed.h:56,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/arduino/mbed-bridge/Arduino.h:14,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.h:9,
> from c:\Users\sbrink\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MCP4725/MCP4725.h:10,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\Documents\Arduino\philipsproject\ppg_signal_generator.h:6,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\Documents\Arduino\philipsproject\ppg_signal_generator.c:1:
> C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/mbed-os/drivers/BusIn.h:25:1: error: unknown type name 'namespace'
> namespace mbed {
> ^~~~~~~~~
> C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/mbed-os/drivers/BusIn.h:25:16: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before '{' token
> namespace mbed {
> ^
> In file included from C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/mbed-os/mbed.h:57,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/arduino/mbed-bridge/Arduino.h:14,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.h:9,
> from c:\Users\sbrink\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MCP4725/MCP4725.h:10,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\Documents\Arduino\philipsproject\ppg_signal_generator.h:6,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\Documents\Arduino\philipsproject\ppg_signal_generator.c:1:
> C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/mbed-os/drivers/BusOut.h:24:1: error: unknown type name 'namespace'
> namespace mbed {
> ^~~~~~~~~
> C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/mbed-os/drivers/BusOut.h:24:16: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before '{' token
> namespace mbed {
> ^
> In file included from C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/mbed-os/mbed.h:58,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/arduino/mbed-bridge/Arduino.h:14,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.h:9,
> from c:\Users\sbrink\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MCP4725/MCP4725.h:10,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\Documents\Arduino\philipsproject\ppg_signal_generator.h:6,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\Documents\Arduino\philipsproject\ppg_signal_generator.c:1:
> C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/mbed-os/drivers/BusInOut.h:24:1: error: unknown type name 'namespace'
> namespace mbed {
> ^~~~~~~~~
> C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/mbed-os/drivers/BusInOut.h:24:16: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before '{' token
> namespace mbed {
> ^
> In file included from C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/mbed-os/drivers/SPI.h:27,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/mbed-os/mbed.h:65,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/arduino/mbed-bridge/Arduino.h:14,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.h:9,
> from c:\Users\sbrink\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MCP4725/MCP4725.h:10,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\Documents\Arduino\philipsproject\ppg_signal_generator.h:6,
> from C:\Users\sbrink\Documents\Arduino\philipsproject\ppg_signal_generator.c:1:
> C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1/cores/mbed-os/platform/SingletonPtr.h:22:10: fatal error: new: No such file or directory
> #include 
> ^~~~~
> compilation terminated.
>
> Using library Wire at version 2.0.0 in folder: C:\Users\sbrink\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\SparkFun\hardware\apollo3\2.2.1\libraries\Wire
> Using library MCP4725 at version 0.4.0 in folder: C:\Users\sbrink\Documents\Arduino\libraries\MCP4725
> exit status 1
>
> Compilation error: exit status 1

which seemed to be leading me down the wrong path so I reverted back to the original code in platform.h and have since found myself here on stackoverflow asking for your assistance.